# Forwarding WAN traffic coming in to VPN Server to VPN client and then to device on client LAN

Tags: openvpn, iptables, forwarding, wan, traffic

Here's a synopsis of what I'm trying to accomplish. My Internet connection is double NAT'd and I have no ability to port forward or bridge the upstream router so that my router can accept incoming connections. I can't even use incoming IPV6 because it's blocked for incoming traffic. This prevents me from being able to remotely connect to my security cameras, my thermostat, and other various devices sitting on my private LAN.

I do have a router running AdvancedTomato that is running OpenVPN (double NAT) and a friend that also has a router running AdvancedTomato but his router is wide open to the WAN with a public IPV4 IP address and he is ok with me using his connection to tunnel my way back in to my LAN. He's ok with whatever I need to do to make it work. I have my router setup as the VPN Client and his router is setup as the VPN Server. The VPN server is on VLAN 10.1.0.0 and the VPN client is on VLAN 10.0.0.0. His router is on 10.1.0.1 and mine is on 10.0.0.1. Both subnets are able to talk back and forth to each other. From his LAN I can easily log in to the web interface of my security camera as if I were sitting at home.

But the part that I am struggling with is that I don't know how to route incoming WAN traffic on his router on say port 5000, to the VPN server, from the VPN server to the VPN client, and finally from the VPN client to my camera whose IP address is 10.0.0.2.

I have attached my crudely hand-drawn topology since I hope it shows it better than I could explain.

[image: my topology]

Anyway, I imagine it will involve using iptables on the server and the client but I haven't had any luck with any of the examples I have seen.